# When a songwriter says "you deserve" to a girl, what makes the girl deserving?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In [*That's What I Like*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMivT7MJ41M), Bruno Mars describes luxuries and says "you deserve it baby".

In [*Treat You Better*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY2yjAdbvdQ), Shawn Mendes describes a lacking relationship and says "any girl like you deserves a gentleman".

Neither describes what's so special or compelling about the girl. For what purpose?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a statement about the girl's specific characteristics, it is expressing the singer's affirmation of her worth and value in his eyes.